# How to create Side Menu on right side in Swift 3.0?

Tags: swift3, amslidemenu

I am a beginner and I wanted to create a side menu on the right side.

So far I have a `UIButton` on right top side of `viewController`, what I want is when I click that button I want to `show/hide slide menu` with say 3 items…

when I click each item it will go to the different view controller. In my project, i am showing slide menu in only one viewController using AMSlideMenu. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome on SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do not forget to provide some code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and format your question properly, using the [provided markdown options](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Share your concerned code. how you're implemented AMSlideMenu for one viewController?

Comment: @NSIceCode no i have not followed that i am new so i need step by step or if code is available

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anuj just follow the steps-

1. Create a `SideMenuViewController` which is sub class of `UIViewController` , using storyboard how it will look according to the requirement.
2. Add this `SideMenuViewController` and its view as a child view controller in parent view controller by `UIButton` click.
3. When you done, remove `SideMenuViewController` from parent View controller and remove its view from parent view.

Repeat 2 and 3 for all view controllers.

**Updated code** :

Declare in your view controller -

```
var sideMenuViewController = SideMenuViewController()
var isMenuOpened:Bool = false
```

In `viewDidLoad`

```
    sideMenuViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuViewController") as! SideMenuViewController
    sideMenuViewController.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
```

In your `button` Clicked event -

```
  func openAndCloseMenu(){

    if(isMenuOpened){

        isMenuOpened = false
        sideMenuViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        sideMenuViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        sideMenuViewController.removeFromParentViewController()

    }
    else{

        isMenuOpened = true
        self.addChildViewController(sideMenuViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(sideMenuViewController.view)
        sideMenuViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
     }

}
```

**For Animation**:

```
let transition = CATransition()

let withDuration = 0.5

transition.duration = withDuration
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft

sideMenuViewController.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in control in iOS for side-menu. However, you could use different open source libraries to achieve your goal.

Have a look at the following libraries:

https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

The detailed tutorial for this library:

1. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/
2. http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path

Comment: my login page is not with menu ,its a second view controller in which slide menu is there @NSIceCode

Comment: You can go through to these tutorials, both provided sample code at the end, which can give you a good idea and you can use it according to your need.

Comment: could u create a sample for ur side as per my requirement @NSIceCode i all appreciate ur help

Comment: Here on SO we can only guide you with some tutorials or can look into your written code for bugs/errors. Show me if you have tried something?

Comment: i have no idea how to do

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
extension SideMenuVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SideMenuTVCell", for: indexPath) as! SideMenuTVCell
        return cell
    }
}
```